# how can I group json data together with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have some json as and I am trying to group it.
I am trying to do this with javascript. Ideally I would like to have the JSON grouped together and just assign a number to each group so I can loop through it.
My ultimate goal is to have a function so I can choose which key to group by.

I have tried to use a function but have had no success. I am not sure where to go from here.

```
var groupBy = function(array, predicate) {
    var grouped = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var groupKey = predicate(array[i]);
        if (typeof(grouped[groupKey]) === "undefined")
            grouped[groupKey] = [];
        grouped[groupKey].push(array[i]);
    }

    return grouped;
}

var groupData = groupBy(data, function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
     return obj.category;
 });
```

My json is

```
{
  "merchantcontract":"My Angel Dream Day Care Center 1 10137.01",
  "smi_transactiondate":"\/Date(1332831600000)\/",
  "smi_glamount2":5.8700,
  "smi_transactionclass":180870001,
  "smi_transactionclassname":"Residual Agent Commission",
  "smi_contractprodcutidname":"Traditional",
  "smi_agentid":"1d3f44ee-afc3-e011-addf-a4badb1ddef5",
  "smi_primaryagentid":"1d3f44ee-afc3-e011-addf-a4badb1ddef5"
},

{
  "merchantcontract":"My Angel Dream Day Care Center 1 10137.01",
  "smi_transactiondate":"\/Date(1331622000000)\/",
  "smi_glamount2":4.5792,
  "smi_transactionclass":180870001,
  "smi_transactionclassname":"Residual Agent Commission",
  "smi_contractprodcutidname":"Traditional",
  "smi_agentid":"1d3f44ee-afc3-e011-addf-a4badb1ddef5",
  "smi_primaryagentid":"1d3f44ee-afc3-e011-addf-a4badb1ddef5"
},

{
  "merchantcontract":"Eds Overhead Doors 10150.01",
  "smi_transactiondate":"\/Date(1333695600000)\/",
  "smi_glamount2":11.9300,
  "smi_transactionclass":180870001,
  "smi_transactionclassname":"Residual Agent Commission",
  "smi_contractprodcutidname":"Traditional",
  "smi_agentid":"1d3f44ee-afc3-e011-addf-a4badb1ddef5",
  "smi_primaryagentid":"1d3f44ee-afc3-e011-addf-a4badb1ddef5"
},
```

What I need is for all the same merchant contract to be group, and all the residual to be grouped within those so I can add up the glamount2

```
-My Angel Dream Day Care Center 1 10137.01
--Residual //This could be anything
----total of glamount2 in the residual of my angle
--foo
----total of glamount2 in the foo of my angle
```

Comment: This is confusing. What output do you get from your existing function and what is wrong with it?

Comment: I have made changes to my post to better explain.

Comment: @Tom: Do you really need to "regroup" your JSON in order to loop over them and get `glamount2`? Assuming that JSON is contained within an array, `glamount2` should already be accessible to you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something (your intention is confusing to me) but if you just need to iterate over those objects and get a specific property, you don't need to "regroup" them in any way.

Simply iterate over the objects and get whatever property you need:

```
​for(var i=0; i < myjson.length; i++){
    console.log(myjson[i].smi_glamount2);
}​
```

This assumes that those 3 (or more) objects are all contained within a single array like this:

```
var myjson = [{
    "merchantcontract": "My Angel Dream Day Care Center 1 10137.01",
    "smi_transactiondate": "\/Date(1332831600000)\/",
    "smi_glamount2": 5.8700,
    "smi_transactionclass": 180870001,
    "smi_transactionclassname": "Residual Agent Commission",
    "smi_contractprodcutidname": "Traditional",
    "smi_agentid": "1d3f44ee-afc3-e011-addf-a4badb1ddef5",
    "smi_primaryagentid": "1d3f44ee-afc3-e011-addf-a4badb1ddef5"
},
{
    "merchantcontract": "My Angel Dream Day Care Center 1 10137.01",
    "smi_transactiondate": "\/Date(1331622000000)\/",
    "smi_glamount2": 4.5792,
    "smi_transactionclass": 180870001,
    "smi_transactionclassname": "Residual Agent Commission",
    "smi_contractprodcutidname": "Traditional",
    "smi_agentid": "1d3f44ee-afc3-e011-addf-a4badb1ddef5",
    "smi_primaryagentid": "1d3f44ee-afc3-e011-addf-a4badb1ddef5"
},
{
    "merchantcontract": "Eds Overhead Doors 10150.01",
    "smi_transactiondate": "\/Date(1333695600000)\/",
    "smi_glamount2": 11.9300,
    "smi_transactionclass": 180870001,
    "smi_transactionclassname": "Residual Agent Commission",
    "smi_contractprodcutidname": "Traditional",
    "smi_agentid": "1d3f44ee-afc3-e011-addf-a4badb1ddef5",
    "smi_primaryagentid": "1d3f44ee-afc3-e011-addf-a4badb1ddef5"
}];
```

Comment: Well I need to have a smi_glamount2 value for each merchant. So The first two will be added together, then the next one will be on its own.